# Блок при нажатии не меняет цвет

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Учу html и задался вопросом: почему блок при нажатии не меняет цвет если задан псевдоелемент **visited**?

```css
.body {
  background-color: darkslategray;
}

.circle2 {
  background-color: darkgray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 40px;
  box-shadow: 4px brown;
}

.circle2 a {
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}

.circle2 a:visited {
  background-color: brown;
  transition: 700ms;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="circle2">
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: цвет задан у ссылки, а не у блока. А размер ссылки т.к. в ней нет текста = 0.

Comment: Ответы - в ответы

Answer (score 1):

Я поменял местами `<a>` и `<div>` в html-коде и в css-коде заменил `a:visited` на `a:focus`.

```css
.body {
  background-color: darkslategray;
}

.circle2 {
  background-color: darkgray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 40px;
  box-shadow: 4px brown;
}

.circle2 a {
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}

a:focus .circle2 {
  background-color: brown;
  transition: 700ms;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <a href="#"><div class="circle2">
    
  </div></a>
</body>
```

Comment: `:visited` !== `:focus`

Comment: @UModeL ссылка `:visited` будет изначально (до клика), т.к. она указывает на этот же документ

Comment: @DiD Спасибо большое! Буду знать.

Comment: @doogel На самом деле, вероятно, вам нужно по клику ссылки добавить класс элементу `.circle2`, который нужно тоже описать в CSS. Например, класс `.highlight`.